# How to detect renames via CMIS ChangeLog in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, changelog

## CMIS ChangeLog

I am using the [ChangeLog](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#x1-12700015) feature of the [CMIS](https://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html) standard to keep track of what is changing on my [Alfresco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfresco_(software)) server.

For instance, when I create `newfile.txt` the ChangeLog token (value of `<cmis:latestChangeLogToken>`) changes from 1713 to 1735.

## Problem

When I rename `newfile.txt` to `myfile.txt`, the ChangeLog token does not change.

## Question

Is there a way to make Alfresco bump the ChangeLog token whenever a rename happens?

Here is my current `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties`:

```
audit.enabled=true
audit.alfresco-access.enabled=true
audit.alfresco-access.sub-actions.enabled=true
audit.cmischangelog.enabled=true
audit.cmischangelog.sub-actions.enabled=true
```

Comment: Rename is not a move/filing even. It’s a property update.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you have to modify Alfresco's audit configuration file which is responsible for generating CMIS ChangeLog events. This file is `alfresco-audit-cmis.xml` and it can be found inside the `alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar` (version number may vary) which itself is inside `alfresco.war`'s `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

You have to add a PathMap and an AuditPath to that file, as described below:

```
<PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/FileFolderService/rename"
    target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
```

... in `<PathMappings>`, and

```
<AuditPath key="fileFolderRef">
    <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="simpleValue" />
</AuditPath>
```

... in the `<AuditPath key="args">` of `<AuditPath key="UPDATED">`.

At the bottom of this answer I pasted the whole modified `alfresco-audit-cmis.xml` for Alfresco Community 5.2.0 201707 as an example, please note that your base file might differ, so better apply the modifications to your Alfresco's own `alfresco-audit-cmis.xml`.

In order to deploy that file so that it actually gets used by Alfresco, please follow the instructions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48221347/226958

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Audit xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2 alfresco-audit-3.2.xsd">

    <DataExtractors>
       <DataExtractor name="simpleValue" registeredName="auditModel.extractor.simpleValue"/>
       <DataExtractor name="nullValue" registeredName="auditModel.extractor.nullValue"/>
       <DataExtractor name="changeLog" registeredName="CMISChangeLogDataExtractor"/>
    </DataExtractors>

    <PathMappings>
        <PathMap source="/CMISChangeLog" target="/CMISChangeLog" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/FileFolderService/create" target="/CMISChangeLog/CREATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/NodeService/createNode" target="/CMISChangeLog/CREATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/NodeService/setProperties" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/NodeService/addProperties" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/NodeService/setProperty" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/NodeService/removeProperty" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-node/beforeDeleteNode" target="/CMISChangeLog/DELETED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/PermissionService/setPermission" target="/CMISChangeLog/SECURITY" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/PermissionService/setInheritParentPermissions" target="/CMISChangeLog/SECURITY" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/PermissionService/clearPermission" target="/CMISChangeLog/SECURITY" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/PermissionService/deletePermission" target="/CMISChangeLog/SECURITY" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/NodeService/moveNode" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/FileFolderService/moveFrom" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/FileFolderService/rename" target="/CMISChangeLog/UPDATED" />
    </PathMappings>

    <Application name="CMISChangeLog" key="CMISChangeLog">
        <AuditPath key="CREATED">
            <AuditPath key="result">
                <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="changeLog" />
            </AuditPath>
            <AuditPath key="error">
                <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="nullValue" />
            </AuditPath>
        </AuditPath>

        <AuditPath key="UPDATED">
            <AuditPath key="args">
                <AuditPath key="nodeRef">
                    <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="changeLog" />
                </AuditPath>
                <AuditPath key="nodeToMoveRef">
                    <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="changeLog" />
                </AuditPath>
                <AuditPath key="sourceNodeRef">
                    <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="changeLog" />
                </AuditPath>
                <AuditPath key="fileFolderRef">
                    <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="simpleValue" />
                </AuditPath>
            </AuditPath>
            <AuditPath key="error">
                <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="nullValue" />
            </AuditPath>
        </AuditPath>

        <AuditPath key="DELETED">
            <AuditPath key="node">
                <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="changeLog" />
            </AuditPath>
        </AuditPath>

        <AuditPath key="SECURITY">
            <AuditPath key="args">
                 <AuditPath key="nodeRef">
                    <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="changeLog" />
                 </AuditPath>
            </AuditPath>
            <AuditPath key="error">
                <RecordValue key="value" dataExtractor="nullValue" />
            </AuditPath>
        </AuditPath>        
    </Application>

</Audit>
```

This "solution" is very inconvenient and might not be complete, so if you know any better method please post a new answer, thanks a lot! :-)