# How to modify Alfresco's out-of-the-box audit configuration

Tags: alfresco, audit

I am trying to modify the PathMappings of the "CMISChangeLog" audit application bundled out-of-the-box in Alfresco 5.

I have found these PathMappings in `alfresco-audit-cmis.xml` which can be found in Alfresco's source code, so I modified this XML file and put it into `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/audit/alfresco-audit-cmis.xml` (thinking that would override the out-of-the-box application) before restarting Alfresco. Problem:

```
ERROR [audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl] Failed to load audit model: file:/home/nico/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/audit/alfresco-audit-cmis.xml
org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelException: 00120000 Audit application key 'CMISChangeLog' is used by: AuditApplication[ name=CMISChangeLog, id=3, disabledPathsId=381]
  at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState.cacheAuditElements(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:646)
```

How to override this out-of-the-box audit application?

Grepping through my server I found out that the default audit application's XML file is stored at `alf_data/contentstore/2017/12/22/18/23/82dfdccd-6ab9-4091-8b7c-d37d4bcf1627.bin` but I haven't found it in the Node Browser:

[image]

Note: I don't want to create a *new* audit application. I must modify the existing one (*because I want Alfresco's CMIS ChangeLog to take into account more events*).

Answer (score 1):

The XML file is actually in `alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar`, which itself can be found in Alfresco's WAR file.

So, if you have an already running Alfresco server, here is the procedure:

1. Stop Alfresco
2. `mkdir -p /tmp/unjar`
3. `cd /tmp/unjar`
4. `unzip $ALFRESCO/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.2.g.jar` (adapt for another version number if necessary)
5. Do the modifications you want inside the extracted file `alfresco/audit/alfresco-audit-cmis.xml`
6. `zip -r ../alfresco-repository-5.2.g-custom.jar *`
7. `cp ../alfresco-repository-5.2.g-custom.jar ALFRESCO/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/`
8. Restart Alfresco